# Validating blank django form field not working

Tags: django, django-forms

I always use the following code to validate a form to prevent blank form submission. It always works in Django 1.8 but for some reason is not working in Django 2.2.

Here is the form

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ['category', 'item_name', 'quantity']

    def clean_category(self):
        category = self.cleaned_data.get('category')
        if category == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required')
        return category


    def clean_item_name(self):
        item_name = self.cleaned_data.get('item_name')
        if item_name == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required')
        return item_name
```

Here is the model

```
class Device(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=False, null=True)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the relevant model?

Comment: Why not specify `min_length` in the field you are working with?

Comment: Did you by any chance set `blank=True` in the field of your model?

Comment: I edited the question and added the model. I don't want to use the model validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are specifying these fields as `blank=True` and `null=True` in your model so change those attributes

```
class Device(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
```

Or by default if you don't specify these `blank` and `null` attribute then it will be false by default so this should work also

```
class Device(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**EDIT** based on the comment:
Like the Willem said you need to check for None.You can do like this.

```
def clean_category(self):
    category = self.cleaned_data.get('category')
    if not category:
        raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required')
    return category
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understand that too. I apologize that my question seems to be not very clear. I want to understand why the validation did not work. It worked well with Django 1.8. Is there any change to Django 2.2 that made this not to work?

Comment: greate arjun and @Willem
This worked:

```def clean_category(self):```
        ````category = self.cleaned_data.get('category')````
       ````if not category:````
              ````raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required')````
        ````return category````

Comment: @simplyvic: well than normally it is a `None`, since the empty string and `None` are "falsly" values.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you did not check fro `None`, but nevertheless. I think you aim to do too much work yourself. You can just specify that the field is [**`required=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#required), this will:

> By default, each Field class assumes the value is required, so if you pass an empty value - either **`None` or the empty string (`""`)** - then `clean()` will raise a `ValidationError` exception.

So we can make the fields required with:

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    item_name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ['category', 'item_name', 'quantity']
```

That being said, it is rather "odd" to specify [**`blank=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#blank) since this actually means that the field is not required in model forms. `blank=True` does not mean that the empty string is allowed, since even with `blank=False`, you can store empty strings in the field. A `ModelForm` will define (most of) its validation based on the model it "wraps", so that means that if you define the model better, you remove a lot of boilerplate code. Therefore I would advise eliminating `blank=True`.

Comment: I understand that this method is like adding more line of unnecessary code to the application since the model can take care of that. I want to understand why it is not working. Is there any change to django 2.2 from 1.8 that caused this type of validation not to work?

Comment: @simplyvic: likely because it is not in the `.cleaned_data`, so you should check for `None` (as is written at the top of the answer).

Comment: I checked for ```None``` too but that didn't work. I realized that the ```None``` works with integer and ```ForeignKey``` fields

Comment: @simplyvic: it might help if you `print(item_name)` and thus check what exactly is passed to it.

Comment: This worked fine.

```def clean_category(self):
    category = self.cleaned_data.get('category')
    if not category:
        raise forms.ValidationError('This field is required')
    return category```